# Alert(""); Function using PhoneGap and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

Using jQuery Mobile, I want an alert to display when the user opens a page

```
<div data-role="page" id="page3">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Three</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        <script>alert('How are you');</script>  
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

But the above code shows the alert on the startup of the app and when I open the page it does nothing. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: open the page? what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQueryMobile there are [specific events](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html) to know when the page loads.

You should instead try the following (put this in your head element, before the body):

```
<script>
$('#page3').live('pageshow', function() {
   alert('Page ' + $(this).attr('id') + ' about to be shown');
});
</script>
```

You could also handle instead the 'pagebeforeshow'/'pagecreate' events.

Comment: You can also use `this.id` - no need to create a new jQuery event in that function if you don't need it anyway.

Comment: sure you can use directly this.id to get the id - but that doesn't create a new jquery *event*, does it ?! - if you want to overoptimize the speed of a simple example.
that was just to show Lucas that he can then get the jquery object of the current page to do whatever he wants with it (I really doubt he wants to keep that alert there..)

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this. It is assumed this div is loaded after page load.

Accessed with div Id.

```
$('#page3').load(function() {
    alert("loaded....");
});
```

Accessed with div class.

```
$('.page').load(function() {
    alert("loaded....");
});
```

Comment: @A I guess people don't like the opening-bracket-in-a-new-line style, +1 for you to even things out

Comment: Its not about liking, new line opening brackets in javascript is wrong :) Watch javascript good parts by Douglas crockford :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script>
    $("div[data-role=content]").eq(0).ready(function() {
        alert('How are you');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `<head>` portion of your page place the following:

```
<script>
    $(document).on('pageshow','#page3',function(){
        alert('How are you');
    });
</script>
```

**Note:** the .live() method has been deprecated. See [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/) for more details about why. Also the .on() method is preferred but does require that you are using jQuery 1.7+. If you are pre jQuery 1.7 use delegate instead.

```
<script>
    $(document).delegate('#page3','pageshow',function(){
        alert('How are you');
    });
</script>
```